# GO-GARCH using Fast-ICA rmgarch package with MVNORM distribution

Tags: r, time-series, estimation, garch, independent-component-analysis

R package [`rmgarch`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/vignettes/The_rmgarch_models.pdf) by Ghalanos estimates the GO-GARCH model using fast-ICA.

I have read that ICA aims to separate a multivariate signal into additive sub-components, by assuming they are **non-Gaussian** and statistically independent from each other.

However, the `rmgarch` package still assumes the `mvnorm` distribution. How is this possible?

On page 12, it explicitly states:

> The objective is to decompose the observed $x = [x_1, ..., x_n]$
>   into additive statistically independent and non-Gaussian components, factors $s = [s_1, ..., s_n]$ and a linear matrix $B$, such that $x = Bs$

How is it possible for the factors to be non-Gaussian and still assume an Multivariate Normal Distribution?

Comment: Neither the time series itself nor its residuals are normal, only the standardized residuals are. Might that be it?

Comment: So, the standardized residuals of the factors are assumed to have mvnorm, but the 
factors themselves (and their residuals) are not? (btw: thank you very for all your contributions in this forum, your answers are gold)

Comment: The assumption is made on standardized residuals/innovations. From there one can derive distributions of unstandardized residuals and raw data, and these can be shown to be nonnormal. Back to your original question: I do not actually know how ICA works for GO-GARCH, it is just my guess.

Comment: thank you very much Prof. Hardy !

Comment: The definite answer could be extracted from p. 10-14 in the package's [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmgarch/vignettes/The_rmgarch_models.pdf) if you need it. There, GO-GARCH and its estimation by ICA are discussed.

Comment: My trouble is when it the ICA approach is when they say "the GO-GARCH
model is greatly simplified so that the conditional log-likelihood function is expressed as the sum of the individual conditional log-likelihoods, derived from the conditional marginal densities of the factors, i.e., GH(yit).

Comment: GH makes sense there. Replacing that with MVNORM does not make sense to me, since the factors are assumed to be non-Gaussian and so $\epsilon$ cannot be gaussian either.

Comment: Update: $f_t$ were the standardized factors, thus the mvnorm. Thanks a lot Prof. Hardy!

Comment: I appreciate your gratitude. I wish I had the energy to write an explicit answer, but it would require a bit more time and focus than I am ready for. You could write an answer yourself if you have grasped the essence. This way it could serve as a reference for other users. Best of luck with your modelling!